# Accessing DOM element ASYNC without hanging UI

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a long page with 500+ lines in grid. It could be more. Columns [Quantity], [Unit Price] and [Gross Total] are connected with each other. Like if I add quantity 3 and add price 33 then it will multiply 3 with 33 and add result in Gross Price.

Everything works fine when I have limited lines like 100 or 200. Problems comes when no of lines grows. For example 300 + lines, then browser gets ill responsive for a while like 10 to 20 seconds.

[image]

What I do in background is calculation in JavaScript. I have a simple method which will run on focus out of text box of each line and calculate it price and place it in Gross Total field and then invoke another method that will calculate Grand Total by obtaining values of Gross Total of all lines (If lines are 300 then it will go for all 300 lines one by one) and then add value in Grand Total.

I think the way I am calculating is the issue and it stuck UI of browser for a while. Is there any way to fix this? Like async? Or picking  DOM elements async without hanging UI? BTY am using jQuery for getting and updating values in textboxes.

Comment: Please share your js code with us, so we can help

Answer (score 1):

A long time ago i did a very similar thing.

The answer is as simple as not recomputing the whole grid. You just need to track the delta.  So if the grand total is 100 when you enter a text box with the value of 10, and it changes to 20, then you know the new value of grandtotal is 110 without having to recompute everything 100 + (20 - 10)

grandTotal += (onExitValue - onEnterValue)